# how to change the value of uilabel after clicking the row

Tags: iphone, uitableview

What I am having is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = customCell;
        self.customCell = nil;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.title.text = @"iPhone!";
            cell.date.text = @"December 25, 2009";
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.png"];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.title.text = @"Second Cell";
            cell.date.text = @"December 26, 2009";
            //Put in your own image. Make sure it is 120 by 100
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}




// Override to support row selection in the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"index %d",indexPath.row);
    NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection: 0];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject: index];
    cell.title.text = @"tetete";
    [self.myTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: array withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

My purpose is if you click on the a row, you will change the text of label of this row.

However, reloadRowsAtIndexPath will invoke cellForRowAtIndex and this time it will assign the old text to the uilabel

My question : how should I change so that I can change the value of the uilabel after click on the row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set value to the label in the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And can access the cell by the line,

```
NSIndexPath * path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
        UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you do with the label in didSelectRow it will always change when you scroll because cellForRow will be called and the labels will be replaced with what you hard-coded

Why don't you put the text and date label strings in an array of dictionaries?
for instance

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:@"iPhone!" forKey:@"title"];
[dict setValue:@"December 25th, 2009" forKey:@"date"];
[array addObject:dict];
[dict release];
dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:@"Second Cell!" forKey:@"title"];
[dict setValue:@"December 26th, 2009" forKey:@"date"];
[array addObject:dict];
[dict release];
```

Then in your `-cellForRow` replace

```
cell.title.text = @"iPhone!";
```

with

```
cell.title.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

and the same for date

and in `-didSelectRow`

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:@"test!" forKey:@"title"];
[dict setValue:@"December 27th, 2009" forKey:@"date"];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:dict];
[dict release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Im under the impression your Cell is a subclass of a `UITableViewCell`. With that said, try the below code... In this example replace `YourCustomCell` with the name of your subclassed `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"index %d",indexPath.row);
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection: 0];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject: index];

// This is where you make the pointer to your cell.
YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];

cell.title.text = @"tetete";
[self.myTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: array withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```